# Two-tier farm serving 10GB of data

Tags: sharepoint-server, configuration

Technet article [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758647.aspx)  describes a small two-tier farm as capable *of low usage load (a few requests per minute up to very few requests per second), and a relatively small volume of data (10 or more gigabytes)* and a medium three-tier as *a data store of one or two terabytes*.

I have a Customer who wants to move from the cloud to on-premise. The number of users is low (ca. 100), the size of data is several hundred GBs now, but we have to plan for 1-3TB. The data requires high availability.

Am I right to assume that the minimum hardware requirements, following the [Hardware Requirements](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx) article, in this scenario would be:

- 2 web servers - 12 GB RAM,
  64-bit, 4 cores
  80 GB for system drive  EACH
- 3 application servers (including 2 for search and crawl) - 12 GB RAM,
  64-bit, 4 cores
  80 GB for system drive  EACH
- 1 search database server, 16 GB RAM, 64-bit, 8 cores, 80 GB for system drive
- 2-3 content database servers, 16 GB RAM, 64-bit, 8 cores, 80 GB for system drive + 3TB for the actual data
- 1 database server for other databases, 16 GB RAM, 64-bit, 8 cores, 80 GB for system drive
- 1 server for Office Web Apps - 12 GB RAM,
  64-bit, 4 cores
  80 GB for system drive

Please feel free to correct/modify/share your experience about any of my assumptions above. 
How much of it can be virtualized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 100 user, I think that many servers are waste.what i would do

1. 2 Servers with WFE role( load balanced) along with all services.
2. 2 SQL Server with Always-On configuration.( it will host the All databases[content,config, services])
3. 1 server for the OWA

this will give you the maximum. But I know, in many orginzation they are looking dedicated server for the dedicated roles even load is not too much. You can add 3rd SharePoint server with App server role( CA, search service).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I kindda agree with you, but how at this point should I treat Microsoft suggestions (10GB - two-tier, 2 TB three-tier) from the first article?